# Ionic Vue Firebase Storage GetDownloadURL on Capacitor IOS

Tags: ios, vue.js, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I have a blog/post that is being created using Ionic 6 Vue 3.
On the post creation we can attach a HeroImage or Attachment File
These are stored on the Firebase Collection and can be returned easily on the post using the Web by Calling the Collection item using the GetDownloadURL function

`const url = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, fileName))`

When I call the same routine via IOS having deployed using Cap Sync IOS all the logging I do before this is invoked but nothing is returned in the IOS logs
Having extracted to it's own function

```
 async GetDownloadUrl(fileName, ContentId, type) {
            console.log('attempting ',fileName,ContentId,type)
            const url = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, fileName))
            console.log('Generated GET signed URL:');
            console.log(url);
            console.log('id',ContentId, 'and type ', type)
        }
```

Web Returns (invokes the child function then gets the response later *I get async/await*) will update the local collection with download URLs once I get the URLs to resolve on IOS

```
attempting  post/qv2Be2fBGcOzfSpW5jic/AugConnect22.png qv2Be2fBGcOzfSpW5jic HeroImg
main.js?ead5:187 Generated GET signed URL:
main.js?ead5:188 https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dgsa-test.appspot.com/o/post%2Fo2QVuFVIIYIxlFn68c9y%2Fattachment%2FDaily%20Action%20Sheet.pdf?alt=media&token=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
main.js?ead5:189 id o2QVuFVIIYIxlFn68c9y and type  Attach
```

IOS Returns

````
⚡️  [log] - attempting  post/pxpA2TaXas1uuAVrgFDq/attachment/understanding_muscle_protein_dynamics_technical_co.pdf pxpA2TaXas1uuAVrgFDq Attach
⚡️  [log] - attempting  post/qL8sByCPSzRZtaEqTz2d/attachment/A-Virtual-Calendar-May_Jun_July-Expo.pdf qL8sByCPSzRZtaEqTz2d Attach
⚡️  [log] - attempting  post/qv2Be2fBGcOzfSpW5jic/AugConnect22.png qv2Be2fBGcOzfSpW5jic HeroImg```

Any ideas or suggestions appreciated
````

Comment: Kindly, did you find a solution? i think this is related to ```capacitor://localhost```